# Understanding how relationship sides works

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-recommendation, relational-theory, data-integrity

So, I have this relations on my tables (see image) and I need to understand some things. I'll enumerate what I understand and what I need from yours is to say if I'm right or not and in case I'm not give me the good answer.

If `general_orders_id` is FK on `natural_person` and `legal_person` tables if I set onUpdate and onDelete to `CASCADE` what this mean?

1- When I delete a `general_orders` the cascade will delete all the records on `natural_person` and `legal_person` tables?

2- When I delete a `natural_person` what happen with the `general_orders` that points to that person?

In order to maintain a good table structure, data consistency and integrity, what are you're suggestions regarding this topic?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0- `CASCADE` means to 'replicate' the changes that happens on the 'master' table to the 'details' tables. For simplicity, assume the relation (country, city). Each city[detail] belongs to a country[master], or each city is a child of a country. With `cascade`, if you delete a country, all cities belong to that country will be deleted.

In your case, `general_orders` is the master table (call it the parent). When you delete an order, the referenced rows from `natural_person` and `legal_person` will be deleted.

1- No, not all records will be deleted. Only the referenced one will be.

2- Nothing will happen to `general_order` table. (If you delete a city, the country will still be there)

Regarding the design: It depends on your model, but I feel that the design is not right. i.e. I think each order should belong to a 'person', and this person's type is either natural or legal. So, I would have:

```
grnaral_order(id, ..., person_id, ...)
person(id, type[legal, natural])
natural_person(id, name, ...)
legal_person(id, company_name...)
```

This is one way, but not necessarily the best one, because it totally depends on your analysis